# JWPlayer JavaScript integration suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, video, callback, jwplayer

We use JWPlayer for video playback, with only a single player embedded in any page, and suddenly it has stopped executing callbacks, though it does not throw errors when the listeners are registered (for onPause, onPlay, and onComplete).

Embedding continues to work fine. The player responds to user interactions to pause, play etc. However, when these occur no callbacks are triggered.

As part of troubleshooting, I have replaced the callbacks with very simple troubleshooting functions, e.g.

```
jwplayer().onPause( function(event) { alert('pause!'); return true; } );
```

In the JavaScript console for both IE and Chrome, no JavaScript errors are shown. Troubleshooting statements (alerts) around every JWPlayer JavaScript call show that no errors are thrown. Wrapping all calls to JWPlayer in try/catch blocks and alerting any created error messages does nothing.

In the JavaScript console after page load, executing control methods such as jwplayer().play() exhibits the following behavior: does NOT change the player's actual playback state, but DOES trigger callbacks.

The JWPlayer version is "5.9.2156 (Licensed version)".

**EDIT**: Another clue: In the JavaScript console, even when the player is paused, alerting `jwplayer().getState()` shows "PLAYING".

**EDIT**: In our testing, disabling HTML5 mode prevents this bug from appearing, but is not optimal.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: No. The code must work before being deployed, and right now is on an internal development server. My boss wonders whether this may be due to using the licensed version; I believe I've seen some posts elsewhere indicating differences in callback behavior using the licensed vs. unlicensed version.

Comment: Everything is hosted on your servers for JW5, not ours, so we can't diagnose an issue that suddenly started out of nowhere without seeing it. And the licensed version vs unlicensed version should not make a difference.

Comment: Others may have seen this bug as well. I remain hopeful. :) If you would like to know how the code is referenced or used, I can provide further info. I don't think it's helpful to demand links to that which is not public, then throw up one's hands.

Comment: Since you are also working with us over email, here, and the forums, I would recommend you email me a test page or zip package that I can test on my own localhost then. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you have us confused with someone else; we are not working with you over email. Thank you for the offer. We've decided as a workaround to just put HTML5 mode second, after flash mode.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

In the end there was no fix for this bug, but we worked around it by having the player default to flash mode first, then fall back to HTML 5 mode second.

The implication of the bug is that for those users who do not have flash support enabled in their browser, our pre-existing integration with Google Analytics will not work, but this should be a minority of users.

We considered upgrading to JWPlayer 6 but that is not an option at this time, due to a known issue with extra play events being reported.